# Guarantees about C++ infinity()

Tags: c++, floating-point, standards, infinity

Since `<cmath>` originates from the C standard but `<limits>` is native C++, provided that `numeric_limits<double>::has_infinity()` is true (**edit:** and also that `numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559()` is true), does the C++ (98/11/14) standard guarantees anywhere that the followings are always true? The references on MSDN and cplusplus.com don't seem to have offered any useful explanation.

- `isinf(numeric_limits<double>::infinity())`
- `x < numeric_limits<double>::infinity()` given that `isfinite(x)` is true
- `!( numeric_limits<double>::infinity()<numeric_limits<double>::infinity() )`

I ask this question because I want to write a function of the form `f(double x, double upper_bound)`, where the function body will branch according to whether `x` breaches the upper bound or not.

Comment: In pure theory, if the compiler does not define `numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559()` as true, the compiler can still return true for `numeric_limits<double>::has_infinity()` but provide weird semantics (for instance for `<`, that would falsify the last two). Do you have a reason not to test for IEEE 754 floating-point, which would imply the presence of infinity and reasonable semantics for the floating-point operations at the same time?

Comment: @PascalCuoq: well said.  One could add `static_assert(is_iec559())` and have a lot more confidence about assumptions like the OP's.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Thanks. Let's say `is_iec559()` is true. I am concerned about the compatibility between C and C++ libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is little said on `infinity()` in the C++11 standard.  Just that it's the *representation of **positive** infinity*.

`isinf()` belongs in C++ to `<cmath>` which wraps the c math library, and C11 says:  *The isinf macro returns a nonzero value if and only if its argument has an infinite value.*  Hence, you can deduce from that definition that  `isinf(numeric_limits<double>::infinity())` should be granted.

No formal guarantee is given in the standard itself, on the fact that every finite x should be smaler than infinity.  However, if `numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559` is true, then you can base your assumption on the iec 559 aka [Ieee 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard,  which [ensures](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html) positive infinity is larger than ***everything except itself***.